# Why is my JLabel's icon not updating properly?

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

Okay, so say my code looks like this:

```
private void gameBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    gameBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            try {
                if(gameBox.getSelectedItem().equals("file1"))
                    gameLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src/icons/file1.png"))));
                if(gameBox.getSelectedItem().equals("file2"))
                    gameLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src/icons/file2.png"))));
                if(gameBox.getSelectedItem().equals("file3"))
                    gameLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon((ImageIO.read(new File("src/icons/file3.png")))));
                if(gameBox.getSelectedItem().equals("file4"))
                    gameLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src/icons/file4.png"))));
                if(gameBox.getSelectedItem().equals("file5"))
                    gameLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src/icons/file5.png"))));
                if(gameBox.getSelectedItem().equals("file6"))
                    gameLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src/icons/file6.png"))));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GUIMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And the starting icon for `gameLabel` is `file1.png` and the desired action upon changing the item in `gameBox` (which is a combobox) is the `imageIcon` for `gameLabel` changing. 
The problem I'm having, is it won't change until *two* selections are made inside `gameBox` 
After that it works perfectly. 
How do I set it so that it changes on the first change? And why is it not doing that already?

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: Also consider a `Map<String, String>` to associate names.

Comment: @trashgod  Good point, but in this case where the action command seems to map exactly to the name of the resource, I'd be tempted to try something like `String name = gameBox.getSelectedItem(); URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/icons/ + name); gameLabel.setIcon(..`.  But of course since the images should be loaded on construction and cached, your suggestion of a `Map` (or more specifically a **`Map<String, Image>`**) to store/retrieve them makes more sense.

Comment: *"The problem I'm having, is it won't change until two selections are made inside `gameBox` After that it works perfectly."*  1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) One way to get images for an example, is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: It looks like `gameBoxActionPerformed` is your event handler (where would you get the `ActionEvent` parameter from otherwise?) Inside this handler you seem to install *another* actionlistener. Can you show the code that invokes/references the `gameBoxActionPerformed`. I would expect the `actionPerformed` code in the example above to be sitting directly under `gameBoxActionPerformed`, rather than nested in another action handler.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it.

As per mention from geert3 I had nested action listeners, and they were causing issues.

Solution in short:

```
        if(gameBox.getSelectedItem().equals("file1"))
            gameLabel.setIcon((Icon) new ImageIcon("src/icons/file1.png"));
                repaint();
```

Rather than:

```
       if(gameBox.getSelectedItem().equals("file1"))
                gameLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src/icons/file1.png"))));
```

Resulted in exactly what I wanted.